# What is the topology on the product bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, k-theory

If $X$ is a topological Space and $V$ is a vector Space then $X\times V$ forms a vector bundle over $X$, but I do not understand how do we topologise the space $X\times V$ so that it forms a vector bundle over $X$.

Comment: $V$ is (non-canonically) isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$, depending on the base field). Fix such an isomorphism, and use it to give a topology induced from the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$). Then take the product topology for $X\times V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V$ already has a topology usually (e.g. it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$) and then we just use the product topology on $X \times V$, which makes both projections continuous (the one onto $X$ is what makes it a vector bundle)

Comment: And if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: @Parish That's normally not considered. Otherwise pick a topological vector space topology on $V$, it will depend on $V$. For finite-dimensional there is topologically speaking no choice.